# Remove day and hour from timer when reached 0?

Tags: javascript

I am a complete beginner to javascript and unfortunately dont yet know enough about it to make the changes I desire, and thats why I am reaching out here!

So basically I am using a timer that someone else created, but I dont like how the days or hours show as 0 days 0 hours 13 minutes 10 seconds when its only 13 minutes and 10 seconds left.

Is there a way for me to make it display only 13 minutes and 10 seconds left, if its only 13 minutes and 10 seconds left, while also keeping the hours and days in when there are more than 1 day or hour in the timer?

This is the code:

> countdown('06/26/2017 8:00 PM', 'timer'); //date format: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM

```
function countdown(dt, id)
{
  var end = new Date(dt);
  var _second = 1000;
  var _minute = _second * 60;
  var _hour = _minute * 60;
  var _day = _hour * 24;
  var timer;

  function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'THE DAY HAS ARRIVED!'; //Displays when countdown is complete
      return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = days + ' days ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + ' hrs ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + ' mins ';
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + ' secs';
  }
  timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use if conditions to check if days, hours or minutes are greater then 0. If they are greater then 0 then add them to the innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ""; // initialize it to empty string
if(days > 0) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += days + ' days ';
}
if(hours > 0) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + ' hrs ';
}
if(minutes > 0) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + ' mins ';
}

document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + ' secs';
```

This will not show minutes or hours if they are 0 but if you want to show 0 minutes or 0 hours if there are hours before minute and days before hours then you can write additional if conditions.

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ""; // initialize it to empty string
if(days > 0) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += days + ' days ';
  if(hours == 0) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML +=  '0 hours ';
    if(minutes == 0) {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML +=  '0 mins ';
    }
  }
}
if(hours > 0) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += hours + ' hrs ';
  if(minutes == 0) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML +=  '0 mins ';
  }
}
if(minutes > 0) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += minutes + ' mins ';
}

document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += seconds + ' secs';
```